# Tailwind apply method not working properly

Tags: reactjs, npm, tailwind-css, css-modules

Any reason why the @apply method gets left in the css like in the picture instead of compiling normally?

[Inspect css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sKEMQ.png)

[Actual css](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EuBat.png)

Comment: i checked it and it worked for me (i checked it with twillind cli compiler). so my guesses: 1. you have compiler erros, like : `bg-primary-50` is not found. 2. your tailwind configuration is not correct. check this steps to see if everything is setted up correctly : https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/02/tailwindcss-react-project/

Answer (score 1):

`@apply` method looks good for me.
Syntax error in your Editor is not so good linter setting(like stylelint).

By the way, your css is **NOT BUILD** maybe.

You should build to apply the `@apply`